# Terrain Trees weird behaviour after lightmapping

Tags: unity, lighting, terrain

I've been working on this game for quite awhile now and have had this problem ever since I switched from real-time lighting to lightmaps. For some reason the trees that are at X distance from me appear as way larger 2d sprites. I have no clue why this is happening so I thought I would ask here. If you need any further details feel free to ask. I appreciate all the help[image]

Comment: The reason why they turn into sprites at all is because the terrain system converts far away trees into impostors to improve performance.  But them being the wrong size is certainly not intended.